# How to parallelise processing of queue while maintaining order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm working on C# program to analyse video. The basic operation is:

1. Grab video frame
2. Process frame
3. Display frame with annotations
4. Save results to disk
5. Repeat

If steps 2-4 take longer than one frame time (30ms), then it drops frames, which I don't want.

Parallelising would reduce the average time, and thus reduce the likelihood of dropped frames. However, the output must be in the same sequence as the input. E.g. the frames with annotations and the results must appear in the correct order.

The way I currently speed things up is to split the process up into parts and have each feed into a BlockingCollection, e.g. in different Tasks there is

1. Add frame to BC #1
2. Take frame from BC #1, process, put results in BC#2
3. Take results from BC #2, add annotations and display, save to disk.

Rather than split up each part of the process into different threads, what I would like is to have a pool of threads each doing the entire processing of a frame. The problem is how to maintain the order of the results.

For example, I could have each thread put the result into a BlockingCollection, but if frame #2 finishes processing before frame #1, the results will be out of order.

- Any ideas of how to implement this in C#?
- Is there a C# class or library that would be useful?
- What should I use to create the pool of threads to maximise performance?

*Update*

The results should be displayed in close to real-time to the user as the program is for controlling some instrumentation, thus sorting the results afterwards is probably not feasible.

Comment: `MassTransit` nuget package has InMemory Message Queue system. You can publish `Message`with parameter and one of consumer take that message and execute same processes. However consume operation executed in order, return result does not has concern about order. If you consume one by one, your result does not lose order property.

Comment: Could you use a wrapper class for each frame to indicate the ordering and then sort the entire collection immediately before saving to disk?

Comment: @CalC The frames should be processed as they come in, because the processed result should be displayed on the UI in real time.

Comment: How far have you got? Have you tried to use `System.Reactive`, also known as Reactive Extensions? I am using it with good results.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to use `.AsParallel()` from PLinQ:

```
var processedFrames = frames.AsParallel()
                            .AsOrdered()
                            .Select(Process)
                            .ToList();
```

Assuming there is a method

```
ProcessedFrame Process(UnprocessedFrame original)
{
    // ...
}
```

This will process your whole sequence, and you get an ordered sequence of result frames as a result.

Comment: This is interesting, I did not know abount PLinQ. However, the frames should be processed as they come in, as the results also need to be displayed in real time for the user.

Comment: Don't you need to apply AsOrdered? I think by default AsParallel does not preserve order.